# git - delete a previous commit but keep changes from last commit

Tags: git, terminal

How to delete a previous commit but keep changes from last commit in `git`?

**First commit:**

```
nano first //writes "this is first" and save
git add first
git commit -m "first commit"
```

---

**Second commit:**

```
nano second //writes "this is second" and save
git add second
git commit -m "second commit"
```

**Git log:**

```
commit 014179d534ed3185dba994d4df3713334893a2c7 (HEAD -> master)
Author: Email <email@gmail.com>
Date:   Fri Mar 18 20:29:20 2022 +0800

    second commit

commit 22b9f9a0a60b5b52c2b8d3e1981b1db524c9d2fd
Author: Email <email@gmail.com>
Date:   Fri Mar 18 20:22:46 2022 +0800

    first commit
```

I want to delete the `first commit` but keep the `files`. How can I do that?

Comment: One way: `git rebase -i HEAD~2`. Insert standard disclaimer about rewriting pushed history

Comment: @ikegami given that the branch only has two revisions, would `HEAD~2` work if you do not provide `--root`?

Comment: Re "*given that the branch only has two revisions*", That was not stated.  But yes, testing reveals that `git rebase -i --root` is necessary in that situation

Comment: @ikegami fair enough that it is not stated... but that is the feeling it gives, at least :-)

Comment: @eftshift0 Let's just say it's good to cover both situations :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like, you want to convert that into a single commit where you keep both files?

There are many ways... the simplest (least effort):

```
git reset --soft HEAD~ # set branch _pointer_ in previous revision
# files are not changed. second will be in index (check with git status)
git commit --amend -m "this is the squashed version"
```

And you are done.

You could also do:

```
git rebase -i --root
# you will get a list of two revisions
# set the second to be s (or squash)
# save and exit
# rebase starts
# git will show you a commit windows telling you about the squash
# and the comment from both revision
# set it to whatever you want
# save and exit
```

And you are done.